# Get error when I run 'flutter build apk --release'

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, apk

When I run `flutter build apk --release` I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithProguard'. >
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

When I run `flutter build apk --debug` or `flutter build apk --profile`, everything compiles fine.

I posted my log, my Flutter doctor, my pub spec.yaml file and my build.gradle file on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86665).

Has anyone an idea, why this could be?

UPDATE: This question is very similar to mine, but the suggested solution doesn't works for me. [The Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984045/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea)

Okay I found a post on a website, but I'm not sure if I understand what I says... The author had the same error and fixed it by setting the CompileSdkVersion higher on a plug in.

[Here is the post](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/1638/565771667)

How would your do that? And how can I know which Number I have to change? Sorry for dumb questions like that, I'm really new to flutter and dart.

Comment: Can you try this change compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: Same error... :(

Comment: But thanks for your quick idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984045/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: The question seems really different, but the suggested solution did unfortunately not work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I didn't find a way to solve this error...

**My Solution:**

1. I copied the `/lib`-folder of my flutter project, where all my Code
   was stored.
2. I copied the code in my `pubspec.yaml`-file.
3. Then I created a new empty flutter project, and deleted the `/lib`-folder.
4. Finally, I pasted in my old `/lib`-folder, pasted in the `pubspec.yaml`-code (into my new `pubspec.yaml`-file) and run `flutter pub get`.

Now my project works fine again and `flutter build apk --release` don't throws an error anymore.